# Create Virtual Column in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have mysql query like this:

```
$statement=$pdo->prepare("SELECT id AS Activity_ID,type,status,description,
(SELECT SUM(price*worked_hours) FROM tbl_working_hours 
WHERE id_act = Activity_ID) AS total_hours FROM tbl_activity");
```

There is two tables:

1- tbl_activity

2- tbl_working_hours

I am trying to create virtual column for each row based on summary from another table.

Thanks

Comment: And what is your question ?

Comment: query working when I enter manually id, but I want automatically to recognize id of each current row it doesn't work. Each row have different id, and I need sum from another table based on that id of current row

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use subqueries

```
SELECT [...], (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM mytable) AS count FROM myothertable
```

Thats the only solution comming to my mind. The problem is that this way is pretty costly when it comes to performance.

Comment: Do you have any other suggestions?